# Execute code at every step in box2d

Tags: box2d, physics, game-physics, box2dweb

What would it be the way to execute code in each step (solve) of box2d instead of once per frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you meant?

```
var box2DListener = Box2D.Dynamics.b2ContactListener;
var ContactListener = new box2DListener;
ContactListener.PreSolve = function(contact, oldManifold) {
  // some code to be executed before each solve
}
ContactListener.PostSolve = function(contact, impulse) { 
  // some code to be executed after each solve
}
```

It was also covered in [Box2dweb - Collision Contact Point thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10878750/box2dweb-collision-contact-point)

You can find some good examples in [Seth Ladd's Blog](http://blog.sethladd.com/2011/09/box2d-collision-damage-for-javascript.html) and [TheNightOwl's Blog](http://thenightowl.xp3.biz/).